# Converting decimal to three stacks

Tags: plsql, scripting

I'm trying to convert decimal number to, errmm, three stacks using next logic or something like that but i can't get strict alogrythm:

```
1       0   0   1
2       0   1   0
3       0   1   1
4       1   0   0
5       1   0   1
6       1   1   0
7       1   1   1
8       0   0   2
9       0   2   0
10      0   2   1
11      2   0   0
12      1   0   2
13      1   1   2
14      1   2   1
15      2   0   1
16      2   1   0
17      2   1   1
18      2   1   2
```

First suggestion was to user two internal cycles, one for decreasing the input (decimal) and second is for switching between stacks.

Awful semi-try in pl-sql (it's working backwards):

```
declare
type arr_type is table of varchar(32) index by binary_integer;
arr arr_type;
i number := 12;
z number := 0;
x number := 0;
c number := 0;
gg number;
begin
  arr(1) := 'z';
  arr(2) := 'x';
  arr(3) := 'c';
  gg := 0; -- array position
  i  := i + 1;  -- 
    loop
    i  := i - 1;
    gg := gg + 1;
      if arr(gg) = 'z' 
        then 
          z := z + 1;
          --if c > 0 then c := c - 1; end if;
      elsif arr(gg) = 'x'
        then 
          x := x + 1;
          --if z > 0 then z := z - 1; end if;
      elsif arr(gg) = 'c'
        then 
          c := c + 1;
          --if x > 0 then x := x - 1; end if;
      end if;
      --
      if gg = 3 then gg := 0;
      end if;
    if i = 1 then exit; end if;
    dbms_output.put_line(z || ' ' || x || ' ' || c);
    end loop;
end;
```

Thankyou.

Comment: What is the logic behind splitting the number into the three parts? It starts off looking an awful lot like binary, but then we hit 8, which goes to (0,0,2). Why is that not (1,1,2)? What do the three columns represent?

Comment: it is looking awful at 8 cause i don't have fourth and further ranks, so i need to split between three parts.

in fact it can be (1,1,2) for 8 but it will break the sequence.

Comment: Ok, but what is the logic as to why it's (0, 0, 2)? Are we meant to be able to take the three columns and reconstitute the corresponding decimal value from them?

Comment: @Boneist , yeah, i'm expecting ability to convert it both ways.
(0,0,2) was just natural for me as next sequence value.
like using next rank.

Comment: so why is 1 = (0,0,1) but 2 = (0,1,0) and 8 = (0, 0, 2)? If the columns represent (2^2, 2^1, 2^0) (as in binary), then 8 would be either (0, 0, 8) or (1, 1, 2). Why do you have this requirement to split the values out into three columns anyway? What is the purpose behind that?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it further, 8 would be (2, 0, 0).

Comment: Thank you anyway, but i need uniform distribution between vectors.

Comment: Why do you need uniform distribution? What's the reason behind this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that is consistent and backwards compatible, plus it can be done in a single SQL statement:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT LEVEL ID FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 16)
SELECT id,
       FLOOR(ID/4) "2^2",
       4*FLOOR(ID/4),
       ID - 4*FLOOR(ID/4),
       floor((ID - 4*FLOOR(ID/4))/2) "2^1",

       ID - 2*(floor((ID - FLOOR(ID/4))/2)) "2^0"
FROM   sample_data;

WITH sample_data AS (SELECT LEVEL ID FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 16)
-- end of generating sample data for the below query to work on
SELECT id,
       FLOOR(ID/4) "2^2",
       FLOOR( (ID - 4*FLOOR(ID/4)) /2) "2^1",
       ID - 4*FLOOR(ID/4) - 2*FLOOR( (ID - 4*FLOOR(ID/4)) /2) "2^0"
FROM   sample_data;

        ID        2^2        2^1        2^0
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          0          1
         2          0          1          0
         3          0          1          1
         4          1          0          0
         5          1          0          1
         6          1          1          0
         7          1          1          1
         8          2          0          0
         9          2          0          1
        10          2          1          0
        11          2          1          1
        12          3          0          0
        13          3          0          1
        14          3          1          0
        15          3          1          1
        16          4          0          0
```

and just to prove that it's backwards compatible (and that it works for however you spread the values across the 3 columns):

```
WITH sample_data2 AS (SELECT 1 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 2 col1, 0 col2, 0 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 0 col3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                      SELECT 0 col1, 1 col2, 2 col3 FROM dual)
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col1*4 + col2*2 + col3 decimal_number
FROM   sample_data2;

      COL1       COL2       COL3 DECIMAL_NUMBER
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         1          1          2              8
         2          0          0              8
         1          2          0              8
         0          1          2              4
```

---

ETA: Here's a way that takes the results for the pattern for ids = 1 to 7 and simply adds that to the (nth-1) pattern (eg. for id = 8, the pattern is the same as id = 1 (col1 = col2 = col3 -1) but plus 1 in each column), id = 15 is the same pattern, for the 3rd time:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT LEVEL -1 ID FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 21)
SELECT ID,
       col1,
       col2,
       col3,
       col1 * 4 + col2 * 2 + col3 check_col
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               floor((ID-1)/7) + CASE WHEN MOD(ID, 7) IN (1,2,3) THEN 0
                                 --     WHEN ID = 0 THEN 1
                                  ELSE 1
                             END col1,
               FLOOR((ID-1)/7) + CASE WHEN MOD(ID, 7) IN (1,4,5) THEN 0
                                  --    WHEN ID = 0 THEN 1
                                  ELSE 1
                                 END col2,
               FLOOR((ID-1)/7) + CASE WHEN MOD(ID, 7) IN (2,4,6) THEN 0
                          ELSE 1
                     END col3
        FROM   sample_data) "MAIN";

        ID       COL1       COL2       COL3  CHECK_COL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0          0          0          0          0
         1          0          0          1          1
         2          0          1          0          2
         3          0          1          1          3
         4          1          0          0          4
         5          1          0          1          5
         6          1          1          0          6
         7          1          1          1          7
         8          1          1          2          8
         9          1          2          1          9
        10          1          2          2         10
        11          2          1          1         11
        12          2          1          2         12
        13          2          2          1         13
        14          2          2          2         14
        15          2          2          3         15
        16          2          3          2         16
        17          2          3          3         17
        18          3          2          2         18
        19          3          2          3         19
        20          3          3          2         20
```

(I've only put the outer query around the main query to prove that the column values return the correct answer in the check_col; you wouldn't necessarily need the outer query.)

N.B. I am assuming that you only want this for positive integers; I wouldn't like to say what would happen for negative integers.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a method that "shares" the values across the columns more evenly.

Comment: Thank you, that is absolutely what i expected.
Appreciate your help and time.